# Seeking to learn Ruby on Rails - good online tutorials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to teach myself [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails). I am new to web development. I hate reading manuals and learn best by doing, rather than reading. I understand the basics of Ruby on Rails conventions and the idea behind it. But for me the best way to learn how to use stuff is to have a step-by-step guide walk me through stuff like setup, applications, etc.

What are particularly good things in this area? Also, which installation package is the best for someone  totally new to Ruby on Rails (as in, I am learning still about SQL and managing web servers).

Comment: What platform are you developing on?

Answer (score 2):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org have about 10 fantastic guides on Ruby on Rails now, including a "Getting Started" one.

Answer (score 1):

This site lists a lot of good resources from installation, getting your first app running as well as blogs, books and forums you can go to for more help. http://www.softwaredeveloper.com/features/74-ruby-on-rails-resources-tutorials-050207/

Good Luck! Rails is very fun.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really an online tutorial (though you can get a PDF), but the first 200 or so pages of [Agile Web Devlelopment with Rails](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition) is a step-by-step tutorial on how to write an online store (with shopping cart, admin area, etc). The book is also generally a great resource to have around while you're learning Rails, especially when trying to get your head around the "Rails way" of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

For a "learn by doing" experience, take a look at the tutorials from the RailsApps project:

> **[Rails Example Apps and Tutorials](http://railsapps.github.com/)**

If you're new to web development, I suggest starting with this primer:

> **[What is Ruby? And Rails?](http://railsapps.github.com/what-is-ruby-rails.html)**

We're blessed with an abundance of good books, articles, videos, and online courses so pick one that fits your learning style:

> **Recommendations for a [Rails Tutorial](https://tutorials.railsapps.org/rails-tutorial)**

Here's an article that will help you install Rails:

> **[Installing Rails](http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html)**

Welcome to the Rails community!